# Solution of $\nabla^2 f(x,y,z)=-f(x,y,z)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a problem and came across the following equation that I need to solve:

$\nabla^2 f(x,y,z)=-k^2 f(x,y,z)$

where the operator $\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$.

I am looking for the most general solution to this equation. How do I solve it?

Comment: This is the Helmholtz equation.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter: Just out of curiousity what is the difference of this equation to Poissons equation?

Comment: The right-hand side of Poisson's equation should not involve $f$.

Comment: @MrYouMath Think of the Laplacian $\nabla^2$ as an operator on functions, analogous to a matrix $A$ acting on vectors. The homogeneous Poisson equation, Laplace's equation, tells you the kernel of $\nabla^2$. The Poisson equation is like the inhomogeneous equation $Av = b$. And the Helmholtz equation tells you the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are, like solving $Av = \lambda v$.

Answer (score 1):

First I make the ansatz that $f $ is separable, that is $$f=X (x)Y (y)Z (z).$$ Then it follows that $$\frac {X''}{X}+\frac {Y''}{Y}+\frac {Z''}{Z}+k^2=0 \rightarrow \frac {X''}{X}=\alpha^2,\frac {Y''}{Y}=\beta^2+\frac {Z''}{Z}=\delta^2$$ picking your constants such that  $$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\delta^2=k^2$$ and $$\vec{k}\cdot\vec {r}=x\alpha+y\beta+z\delta $$ we have that the solution is in the form $$f (x,y,z)= Ae^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec {r}}+Be^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec {r}}$$
Where $\vec{k}$ serves as a polarization vector (solutions to this equation are eigenfunctions of the wave equation) and $A$ and $B$ are arbritary constants which depend on the initial conditions of the function.